# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jgroups.-$$Lambda$CbeKW6_ggTAEDuiYP5MNn0HcZP8

Tags: java, android, kotlin

My application uses [JGroups](http://www.jgroups.org/), version 4.1.6.Final. My activity invokes `JChannel()`:

```
class MainActivity : Activity() {
  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
      JChannel()
  }
}
```

On an Android 8.0 platform, the call goes through. On an Android 6.0 platform, I get this error:

```
10-18 14:11:43.148  4633  4633 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-18 14:11:43.148  4633  4633 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.horph.jbomb, PID: 4633
10-18 14:11:43.148  4633  4633 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.jgroups.-$$Lambda$CbeKW6_ggTAEDuiYP5MNn0HcZP8
10-18 14:11:43.148  4633  4633 E AndroidRuntime:        at org.jgroups.JChannel.init(JChannel.java:950)
10-18 14:11:43.148  4633  4633 E AndroidRuntime:        at org.jgroups.JChannel.<init>(JChannel.java:125)
10-18 14:11:43.148  4633  4633 E AndroidRuntime:        at org.jgroups.JChannel.<init>(JChannel.java:107)
10-18 14:11:43.148  4633  4633 E AndroidRuntime:        at org.jgroups.JChannel.<init>(JChannel.java:98)
10-18 14:11:43.148  4633  4633 E AndroidRuntime:        at com.horph.jbomb.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:10)
10-18 14:11:43.148  4633  4633 E AndroidRuntime:        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
```

The same APK works just fine on Android 8.0. What could I be running into?

A working example is at https://github.com/allenluce/jbomb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that JGroups relies on resources from Java 8 version, and some of these resources are available only  on API 24 or above (Android 7.0).

[image: Line where problem occurs.].

The `forEach` method, triggered by calling `JChannel`defatult constructor,  is one of these unavailable resources on Android 6.0.  The easier solution is to downgrade JGroups version, and try on Android 6 devices until works.

[Edit]: Based on the another answer here you can find the JGroup source code https://github.com/belaban/JGroups.

Answer (score 1):

#### New Answer

It seems [Android Studio 4.0 (currently in Canary)](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features/#4.0) will support desugaring libraries, so it's worth trying out that version:

> Android Studio now includes support for using a number of Java 8
>   language APIs without requiring a minimum API level for your app.
>
> Through a process called desugaring, the DEX compiler, D8, in Android
>   Studio 3.0 and higher already provided substantial support for Java 8
>   language features (such as lambda expressions, default interface
>   methods, try with resources, and more). In Android Studio 4.0, the
>   desugaring engine has been extended to be able to desugar Java
>   language APIs. This means that you can now include standard language
>   APIs that were available only in recent Android releases (such as
>   java.util.streams) in apps that support older versions of Android.
>
> The following set of APIs is supported in this release:
>
> - Sequential streams (java.util.stream)
> - A subset of java.time
> - java.util.function
> - Recent additions to java.util.{Map,Collection,Comparator}
> - Optionals (java.util.Optional, java.util.OptionalInt and java.util.OptionalDouble) and some other new
>     classes useful with the above APIs
> - Some additions to java.util.concurrent.atomic (new methods on AtomicInteger, AtomicLong and AtomicReference)
> - ConcurrentHashMap (with bug fixes for Android 5.0)

---

#### Old Answer

Android 6 did not support Java 8 lambdas. You can use lambdas on Android Studio but if your dependency is pre-compiled, it seems it stills fails on older SDKs. 
In your case it's due to a method reference used in `JChannel`.

There are at least two ways of solving this:

- Run some weaving over your jar dependendy to translate the bytecode to Java 6 and manually add the `.jar` to your `/libs` folder.
- Download JGroups source code as a library module and compile it inside Android Studio. You can make it a git submodule too.

I thought proguard or R8 would fix this, but I tried adding those to the example project you shared on github without yielding any results.